# WordPress Rest API Route For File Upload

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I created a route that I want to use to process uploaded files:

```
register_rest_route( 'media-gallery-route', 'group_image', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => array( $this, 'routeSaveGroupImage' ),
    )
);      

public function routeSaveGroupImage( WP_REST_Request $request ){
    $buff = $request->get_body();
}
```

URL https://www.test.com/wp-json/media-gallery-route/group_image?_wpnonce=ebb5924f80

I'm using XMLHttpRequest to post my data

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
formData.append('group_id', groupID);
...
xhr.open('POST', url);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');

xhr.send(formData);
```

In my route, I can see the content
the parameter $request

[image]

and if it use get_body()

```
$buff = $request->get_body();
```

[image]

And this is where I'm stuck.  I've Googled and can't seem to figure out how to get the group_id value and the file that was uploaded.

If anyone can provide some tips

**The Solution**

I got it to work by:

a. Removing the setRequestHeader
b. Adding true to open open('POST', url, true);